# Multithreading in C not working properly

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, synchronization, pthreads

So I managed to get my program running but for some reason, no customer walks in the bar unless the customer before him/her leaves the bar first, how can I fix it?
I tried a mutex_lock but I might've implemented it wrong, here is what I have from my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

sem_t sem;
pthread_mutex_t serve = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void Bartender(int);
void EnterBar(int);
void OrderStart(int);
void ServeStart(int);
void ServeDone(int);
void OrderDone(int);
void DrinkBeer(int);
void LeaveBar(int);
void* Customer(void*);

void Bartender(int cid)
{
    ServeStart(cid);
    ServeDone(cid);
}

void* Customer(void* id)
{
    int cid =(int)id;
    EnterBar(cid);
    LeaveBar(cid);
    return NULL;

}

void EnterBar(int cid){
    sem_wait(&sem); //decrease semaphore
    printf("Customer %d enters the bar.\n", cid);
    int cups;

    for(cups=0;cups<(cid%3+1);cups++){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&serve);     
        OrderStart(cid);
        OrderDone(cid);
        DrinkBeer(cid);     
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&serve);
    }
}
void OrderStart(int cid)
{
    printf("Customer %d asks for beer.\n", cid);
    Bartender(cid);
}

void OrderDone(int cid)
{
    printf("Customer %d gets the beer.\n", cid);
}

void DrinkBeer(int cid)
{
    printf("Customer %d drinks the beer.\n", cid);
}

void LeaveBar(int cid)
{
    printf("Customer %d leaves the bar.\n", cid);
    sem_post( &sem ); //increase semaphore
}

void ServeStart(int cid)
{
    printf("Bartender starts to serve customer %d.\n", cid);
}

void ServeDone(int cid)
{
    printf("Bartender is done serving customer %d.\n", cid);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int t;
    long rc;    
    int num_customers = atoi(argv[1]); //number of customers
    int capacity = atoi(argv[2]); //bar capacity

    if(num_customers > 0 && capacity > 0){
        rc = sem_init( &sem, 0, capacity );
        if (rc)
        {
            printf("ERROR; return code from sem_init() is %ld\n",rc);
            exit(-1);
        }
        //pthread_t threads[num_customers];
        pthread_t *threads = (pthread_t*)malloc(num_customers*sizeof(pthread_t));
        if(random() > RAND_MAX / 2)
            usleep(1);
        //rc = sem_init(&sem1,0,capacity);
        //rc = pthread_barrier_init(&barrier1, NULL, num_customers);
        for(t=0; t<num_customers;t++){
                printf("In main: creating thread %d\n", t);
            //printf("CAPACITY: %d\n", capacity);
                rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, Customer, (void* )t);
                if (rc){
                    printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %ld\n", rc);
                    exit(-1);
                }
        }
        for( t=0;t<num_customers;t++)
            pthread_join(threads[t],NULL);

        sem_destroy(&sem); //destroy semaphore
    }
    else{
            printf("ERROR: Both parameters should be a valid positive numbers.");
            exit(-1);
    }

    /* Last thing that main() should do */
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

It should allow multiple customers in the bar, and to leave after the finish drinking their beers, not after the customer before them leaves. Do I need a thread for the bartender?
Any suggestions??

Comment: works for me, compiled and ran the attached code and got:

<snip>
Customer 1 enters the bar.
In main: creating thread 2
Customer 0 leaves the bar.
</snip>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *don't* have the problem you think you have.  I made the following changes.

(1)
    //add globals

```
int count = 0;
pthread_mutex_t mutCount = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

(2) Add to counter of people in bar and print out

```
void EnterBar(int cid)
{
    sem_wait(&sem); //decrease semaphore

    printf("Customer %d enters the bar.\n", cid);    

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutCount);
    count++;
    printf("There are %i customers in the bar\n", count);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutCount);

    int cups;

    for (cups = 0;cups < (cid % 3 + 1);cups++)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&serve);
        OrderStart(cid);
        OrderDone(cid);
        DrinkBeer(cid);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&serve);
    }
}
```

(3) decrement count of customers in bar when they leav

```
void LeaveBar(int cid)
{
    printf("Customer %d leaves the bar.\n", cid);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutCount);
    count--;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutCount);

    sem_post( &sem ); //increase semaphore
}
```

(4) In main change usleep to something worthwhile

```
    if (random() > RAND_MAX / 2)
        usleep(100);
```

(5) I ran with:  barthread 20 15 | grep "There are"

(6) I get the following output:

```
There are 1 customers in the bar
There are 2 customers in the bar
There are 1 customers in the bar
There are 3 customers in the bar
There are 4 customers in the bar
There are 5 customers in the bar
There are 6 customers in the bar
There are 7 customers in the bar
There are 6 customers in the bar
There are 6 customers in the bar
There are 5 customers in the bar
There are 5 customers in the bar
There are 5 customers in the bar
There are 6 customers in the bar
There are 4 customers in the bar
There are 4 customers in the bar
There are 5 customers in the bar
There are 6 customers in the bar
There are 7 customers in the bar
There are 8 customers in the bar
```

Comment: For some reason, I am only getting 1 customer in the bar at all times :/

Comment: Are you using the sleep(int) function that @amb mentioned below?

Comment: No, I just upped the usleep count.

Comment: I changed it to 1000 and is still doing it too fast so only 1 customer is inside at a time

Comment: Now that I look at it the usleep is pointless where it is in your code.  Put a usleep(100) somewhere within the threaded part of the code.  Also you never use `srandom()` so you may be getting the same starting number every time and never executing that statement.

Comment: I'm still getting one customer in the bar -___- I can't believe this! lol

Comment: Stop running on your supercomputer cluster?

Comment: Maybe try some contention for the semaphore by making the number of customers MUCH greater than the capacity.  Something like "pgm 100 5"

Comment: That's funny, I've been trying 100 customers and 4 for capacity the whole time

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

and modify this functions

```
void DrinkBeer(int cid)
{
    printf("Customer %d drinks the beer for 10 seconds.\n", cid);
    sleep(10);
}
void LeaveBar(int cid)
{
    printf("Customer %d leaves the bar (takes 10 sec).\n", cid);
    sem_post( &sem ); //increase semaphore
   sleep(10);
}
```

See how it behaves now. You need some sleep functions in there so the thread can sleep and to observe better how the other threads are working.
Does it function as it should with this modifications ?

Comment: No! This makes the program as slow as it can be!

Comment: The modifications are to see if it is working properly not to remain in the final code. Those functions execute to fast to see how threads are behaving. And you realize that threads are sleeping for 10 seconds when they execute those functions, right ?

Comment: well yes it does, but this does not solve the problem at all :/

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a correct behavior, right ? 
Customer 2 is the first in the bar but leaves after customer 1.

```
[amb@localhost ~]$ ./a.out 3 2
In main: creating thread 0
In main: creating thread 1
In main: creating thread 2
Customer 2 enters the bar.
Customer 2 asks for beer.
Bartender starts to serve customer 2.
Bartender is done serving customer 2.
Customer 2 gets the beer.
Customer 2 drinks the beer for 7 seconds.
Customer 1 enters the bar.
Customer 1 asks for beer.
Bartender starts to serve customer 1.
Bartender is done serving customer 1.
Customer 1 gets the beer.
Customer 1 drinks the beer for 8 seconds.
Customer 2 asks for beer.
Bartender starts to serve customer 2.
Bartender is done serving customer 2.
Customer 2 gets the beer.
Customer 2 drinks the beer for 6 seconds.
Customer 1 asks for beer.
Bartender starts to serve customer 1.
Bartender is done serving customer 1.
Customer 1 gets the beer.
Customer 1 drinks the beer for 4 seconds.
Customer 1 leaves the bar.
Customer 0 enters the bar.
Customer 0 asks for beer.
Bartender starts to serve customer 0.
Bartender is done serving customer 0.
Customer 0 gets the beer.
Customer 0 drinks the beer for 6 seconds.
Customer 2 asks for beer.
Bartender starts to serve customer 2.
Bartender is done serving customer 2.
Customer 2 gets the beer.
Customer 2 drinks the beer for 7 seconds.
Customer 0 leaves the bar.
Customer 2 leaves the bar.
```

Comment: Yes, but customers should be allowed to go in before the user before them enters the bar

Comment: what ? do you mean this line ? Customer 2 drinks the beer for 7 seconds.
Customer 1 enters the bar. Customer 1 does not wait for 2 to drink before getting in the bar.

Comment: You are right, you just added the sleep in drinkbeer and leavebar?

Comment: void DrinkBeer(int cid)
{
    int drinkTime = rand() % 10 + 1;
    printf("Customer %d drinks the beer for %d seconds.\n", cid, drinkTime);
    sleep(drinkTime);
}

Comment: void EnterBar(int cid){
    sem_wait(&sem); //decrease semaphore
    printf("Customer %d enters the bar.\n", cid);
    int cups;

    for(cups=0;cups<(cid%3+1);cups++){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&serve);     
        OrderStart(cid);
        OrderDone(cid);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&serve);
        DrinkBeer(cid);     
    }
}

Comment: It works, but it takes forever if I have 100 customers and a 4 capacity :/

Comment: The sleep functions were to see if the program works as expected. You _remove them_ in the final program. After you remove them you can't fully trust the order of what is being printed in the console because we are talking about multiple threads and they write when they can, and how much they can in that short time. *Also it only seems* to be one customer in the bar because everything happens so fast. That's why I inserted sleep functions, to better understand what is happening.

Comment: Just an FYI, you should unlock the mutex for serve before the consumer starts to drink - pthread_mutex_unlock(&serve); DrinkBeer(cid) -. This is the normal situation in real life.

Comment: I think that mutex is useless, I removed it and everything worked the same way. I think I need to implement a barrier for the bartender and make it a thread.

Comment: Think of the bartender as a file you need to write. You need the mutex or all the threads will write part of the information and everything will be garbage. The bartender can serve only one customer at a time thus mutex. The barrier is used in other purposes that do not apply in this situation. The threads are waiting for bartender not for other threads to finish something.

Comment: But the bartender should be a thread as well, so the customers threads should wait on the bartender to finish serving, no?

Comment: If you go this route (bartender as a thread) you complicate things a lot. You will need a barrier not only on the bartender but on the other n-1 threads because otherwise when the bartender finishes serving a thread, all others will get to be served in the same time. So in this case a mutex is still necessary (be it thread-bartender or just bartender).

Comment: I suppose this is a school related program. When you have time, you should implement some parallel and distributed algorithms (using OpenMP - parallel- or OpenMPI - distributed-) and you will understand better when to use barriers and all other principles about parallel and distributed programming.

Comment: Is not school related, just doing exercises from a book so I can learn all this by myself. I never was too into programming when I was in college and now for works things keep getting more and more complicated so I decided to improve my skills. Thanks for everything! You have done a great job!

Answer (score 1):

What's with all this mutex gunge?  What's wrong with a couple semaphores, one 'barAccess', initialized to the bar capacity, one 'barStaff', init. to the number of bartenders?

```
#define slaughtered (beerCount==10)

{
  beerCount=0;
  wait(barAccess);
  do{
    wait(barStaff);
    sleep(pouringTime);
    signal(barstaff);
    sleep(drinkingTime);
    beerCount++;
  }while(!slaughtered);
  signal(barAccess);
};
```

If this bar has regular customers, you can add another while(true) loop round it with a 'sleep(soberUp);' after each session in the boozer.

It's also easy to vary the number of barstaff during opening time.  Just add more 'barStaff' units or steal some away.

If it gets really busy, you might want to open the lounge bar as well to increase capacity - just all more barAccess units in a loop.

Closing time should be fun.  You need to persuade the customers to leave and not allow any more in.  Maybe the customers should leave if they don't get served in a reasonable time. You could then suck out all the barstaff so the customers can't get served and gather in all the barAccess units so new customers can't get in.  Eventually, the bar will be empty for today.  When you open up the next day, shove in the barstaff first, then the barAccess units and watch the rush to get served!

Comment: Well, the customers leave after finishing what they are supposed to drink (in this case their customer id % 3 + 1 ) and after they finish their last beer, they should leave. The barstaff should always be one, only one person is going to be bar tending. The capacity should be predefined from the command line parameters when executing the program.